# how to set ip in header and then run script with cron job?

Tags: php, http, header, http-headers, pear

i have script this code:

```
require_once 'Request2.php';
$request  = new HTTP_Request2('http://fakevisit.blogfa.com/');
$request->setHeader(array(
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Ip: 88.168.25.98',
    'SomeBull: BeingIgnored',
    'Referer: http://www.google.com',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)'
));

$response = $request->send();
echo "Response body:\n" . $response->getBody();
```

The program is run once every 1 minute Is working correctly.
but in google analytics And other counter scripts Does not add to the visitors!
at this line

```
echo "Response body:\n" . $response->getBody();
```

The entire contents of the page with Script to display the number of visitors are displayed correctly in page.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics and most others use Javascript to populate the hit. If you're calling this via Cron/Scheduled Tasks then you're doing a HTTP request and getting the response, but you aren't executing the Javascript for GA, therefore no hit is added.

Comment: But the page has been requested Page loading is complete

Comment: If you run this via cron/tasks then it gets the response HTML but it won't execute the Google Javascript which adds the hit.

Comment: looking here http://www.injaa.com/test/fake/HTTP_Request2-2.1.1/HTTP/ Each refresh this page add one visit to counter but i want refresh do with cron jobs